# virtualenv without interfering #!/usr/bin/env python

Tags: python, virtualenv, shebang

My application is writen in python 3, and I work in a virtualenv. On my cluster, there is hdp (hortonworks) installed and some scripts require python 2. Those script have #!/usr/bin/env python in the header, but it links to my python 3 installation because my virtualenv is activated. How to solve this ? I can't modify hdp source for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 3):

#### Modifying Your Virtualenv

If you want your virtualenv to *always* be ignored with a `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang (but not with a `#!/usr/bin/env python3` shebang), there's a big-hammer approach that prevents the `python` entry in the `PATH` added by the virtualenv from matching, but doesn't necessarily perform other cleanup:

```
rm "$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python"
```

...or a better-behaved alternative (assuming that you have a `python2.7` in your PATH, and that it's what you want to use):

```
cat >"$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python" <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/env bash
path_prefix=$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:
if [[ $PATH = $path_prefix* ]]; then
  PATH=${PATH#$path_prefix}
fi

unset PYTHONHOME VIRTUAL_ENV
exec python2.7 "$@"
EOF
```

The below will assume you're looking for approaches with a bit more *finesse*.

---

#### Command-Specific Shell Wrapper

If you interact with Hortonworks through a frontend called `hdp`, consider the following a shell function, a wrapper for `hdp` that deactivates the virtualenv:

```
hdp() (
  if [[ $VIRTUAL_ENV ]]; then
    deactivate
  fi
  exec command hdp "$@"
)
```

Because this function is using parentheses instead of curly braces, it runs in a subshell -- a separate copy of the shell environment -- so when it runs `deactivate`, this doesn't impact your parent shell. This also means that the `exec` command causes the subshell to replace *itself* with the `hdp` command, rather than causing your parent shell to terminate.

---

#### Generic Shell Wrapper

If you want to be able to run *other* scripts with your virtualenv temporarily deactivated, consider instead:

```
# wv == "without virtualenv"
wv() (
  if [[ $VIRTUAL_ENV ]]; then
    deactivate
  fi
  exec "$@"
)
```

...such that `wv foo` will run `foo` with the virtualenv deactivated.